# Table design for temporary table accessed by multiple processes and stores 1,000,000,000+ 4-column rows

Tags: mysql, architecture

I am using MySQL for temporary storage of the result of one billion or more results, where the results are calculated by processes executing in parallel.
Each result is calculated using a function [f] on the representations [r1] and [r2] of objects identified respectively by [o1] and [o2].
Currently, I use three tables to execute this process:
(1) A table mapping object identifiers to their representations:

```
mysql> describe v2_3282_fp;
+----------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| objid          | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| representation | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

(2) A table holding jobs that each compute process should retrieve amd calculate:

```
mysql> describe v2_3282_job;
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| jobid    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| workerid | int(11)             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pairid1  | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pairid2  | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

(3) A table holding the results of compute jobs:

```
mysql> describe v2_3282_res;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| resultid  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| pairid1   | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pairid2   | text                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pairscore | double(36,18)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

(the pairscore type is dynamically determined during execution, and not fixed to (36,18) .)

Once the representations have been registered, one process continually scans the result table for new results to transfer to an object existing in memory, and the remaining processes retrieve jobs to compute until they receive a job with a pair of identifiers signalling the end of computation.

During unit tests with 1,000,000 or so computations, this system works just fine.
However, as the demands to use this system have grown to 1,000,000,000+, I see that the system eventually gets bogged down in swapping back and forth between memory and disk.
When I check the system memory and swap space in use, the system memory used is completely used, but typically less than 20% of swap is used.

I have read that MySQL performance is best when entire tables can be read into memory, and resorting to disk I/O is the major bottleneck.
This seems to be the case for me as well, as running computations on my systems with 12 GB and 16 GB of RAM eventually requires more and more time between worker process cycles, though my lone system with 64 GB never seems to encounter this issue.

While the straightforward answer is, "Hey buddy, buy more RAM.", I think there is a more fundamental design issue that is causing my system to degrade as the demands grow.  I know that MySQL is a well-engineered product widely used, and that database and table design consideration can greatly impact performance.

So without resorting to the brute force resolution of buying more memory, I am looking for suggestions on how to improve the engineering of the MySQL table design I came up with.
While I know the basics of MySQL table normalization and can create queries to implement my needs, I do not know much about each type of database engine, the details of indexing, and other database-specific design considerations.

The questions I have are:
(1) Would performance be any different if I split the result and job tables into smaller tables instead of single large tables? (I think not.)
(2) I currently issue a limit clause programatically to retrieve a fixed number of results in each retrieval cycle.  However, I don't know if this can be further optimized over the simple "SELECT ... FROM [result table] LIMIT start, size". (I think so.)
(3) Does it make sense to tell the worker processes to sleep between cycles in order to let MySQL "catch up"? (I think not.)

My appreciation in advance for any advice from those experienced in database and table design.

Comment: After a bit more research and reading of the MySQL chapters of "PHP and MySQL for dynamic websites" by Larry Ullman (a bit outdated but still relevant), I have seen that my table designs and queries are very inefficient.  I will be making changes and report the difference in results to this question.